# Fonts for particular languages

Tags: fonts

I have Sanskrit and English in the same buffer, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have one font for Sanskrit and another for English. Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but perhaps this would work: https://github.com/rolandwalker/unicode-fonts